# Making a JavaScript object using literal notation

Tags: javascript, syntax

I’m making a JavaScript object with literal notation, but I’m not sure how to make the object receive parameters like this:

```
hi.say({title: "foo", body: "bar"});
```

instead of `hi.say("foo", "bar");`.

Current code:

```
var hi = {
    say: function (title, body) {
        alert(title + "\n" + body);
    }
};
```

The reason why I want that is because I want people to be able to skip the title and just put the body, and do the same for many other parameters.

So that’s why I need something like how we can use jQuery functions’ parameters `{parameter:"yay", parameter:"nice"}`

P.S. I’m open too for modification of the current method – keeping in mind that there would be many parameters, some required and some optional, and which cannot be ordered in a specific way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no special parameter syntax for that, just make the function take a single parameter, and that will be an object:

```
var hi = {
  say: function(obj) {
    alert(obj.title + "\n" + obj.body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var hi = {
    say: function(options) {
        if (options.title) alert(options.title + "\n" + options.body);
        else alert('you forgot the title!');
    }
}


hi.say({ //alerts title and body
    "title": "I'm a title",
    "body": "I'm the body"
});
hi.say({ //alerts you for got the title!
    "body": "I'm the body."
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hi = {
  say: function( opts ) {
     var title = (opts.title)?opts.title:"default title";
     var body = (opts.body)?opts.body:"default body";

     // do whatever with `body` and `title` just like before
     // ...
  }
};
```